# Transliterate this Sama Veda Mantra

Tags: vedas, sanskrit, sama-veda, language, transliteration

This is from the Sama Veda; Google Translator didn't help me with the transliteration, and I don't speak Sanskrit either. Can someone provide a transliteration.?[image]

Comment: The translation is already given in the picture only. "Oh Indra!....might."

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Sorry what I meant was the pronounciation. Like how to say the mantra spelt out in english.

Comment: U mean transliteration.?

Comment: Sorry, don't know the exact terminology for it but something like this: ॐ भूर्भुव॒ स्सुवः॑
तत्स॑ वि॒तुर्वरे᳚ण्यं॒
भर्गो॑ दे॒वस्य॑ धीमहि
धियो॒ यो नः॑ प्रचो॒दया᳚त् ॥ = oṃ bhūr bhuvaḥ suvaḥ
tat savitur vareṇyaṃ
bhargo devasya dhīmahi
dhiyo yo naḥ pracodayāt. A similar thing to this for the mantra above, I am looking for the pronouncaition spelt out alphabetically

Comment: Yeah, that's transliteration. It's ok man, no need to be sorry. ..

Answer (score 1):

It says, in IAST,

> *endra pṛkṣu kāsu cin nṛmṇaṃ tanūṣu dhehi naḥ**
> *satrājid ugra pauṃsyam*

*For some reason the *visarga (*ḥ*)* appears to have been rendered with a semi-colon instead of its proper form, which is ः and more like an English colon, without obviously actually being a colon, but it should properly be a *visarga* and the transliteration is *naḥ* not *na;*

However, although IAST is a standard scheme used by academics, it is not the only transliteration scheme available and it is often used with minor alterations.

You can find a transliteration of this verse using a slightly different though very similar scheme on the TITUS database here

https://titus.fkidg1.uni-frankfurt.de/texte/etcs/ind/aind/ved/sv/svk/svk.htm

You will need to navigate to Prapathaka 3.

I note that for whatever reason in neither the Devanagari version you provide nor in the transliterated version in the TITUS database are any accent marks present of any kind. The *Sāma-Veda* was of course meant to be sung, it was set to music, and therefore the manuscripts are generally annotated with a very precise set of accent and other marks. The words are also more or less altered to fit rhythms and songs much as is often done when words are put to music. You can find one version which has been typeset here:

http://www.sanskritweb.net/samaveda/index.html

These alterations may indeed be removed in many editions but I would have expected to see the pitch accent marked in some way even if the full *Sāma-Vedic* accent markings are missing.